# AFNetworking 2.0.3 not working on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I installed AFNetworking via CocoaPods:

```
pod "AFNetworking", '~> 2.0.3'
```

So, the method, which called from standart GET request:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                   parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                      success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
```

calls `- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;` that returns `nil` on iOS 6.

Because AFNetworking uses `NSURLSessionTask` & `NSURLSession` which is introduced in iOS 7.0

And from **[AFNetworking Documentation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide)**:

> **New Requirements: iOS 6, Mac OS X 10.8, & Xcode 5**
>
> AFNetworking 2.0 officially supports iOS 6+, Mac OS X 10.8+, and Xcode 5.

---

Why it calls methods, that appears only in iOS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution:

My API client inherit from `AFHTTPSessionManager` (like in afnetwoking site example).

But if you are using iOS 6 just leave inheritance from `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` like in AFNetworking 1.x versions.

Replace:

```
@interface APIClient : AFHTTPSessionManager
```

to:

```
@interface APIClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

Comment: Doing it this way requires 2 ways of calling e.g. the GET:parameters:success:failure method, because the success and failure block are different in AFHTTPSessionManager and AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. Instead just extend AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (as long as your app supports iOS6)